# How to convert Array of Array of Objects to an Array of Arrays in Angular?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, object

```
[[{ id: 26, type: "Source", name: "Email" }], [{ id: 27, type: "Source", name: "Id" }, { id: 29, type: "Divider", name: "+" }, { id: 30, type: "Source", name: "SupplierId" }], [{ id: 28, type: "Source", name: "CommunityId" }]
```

How do I convert this array of array of object above to an array of arrays like this where the "name" is singled out?

```
[["Email"],["Id","+", "SupplierId"],["CommunityId"]]
```

I have already tried to map it like this:

```
this.exportColumns = columns.flatMap(obj => obj.sourceColumn).map(obj => obj?.name);
```

but I get this outcome:

```
[ "Email", "Id", "+", "SupplierId", "CommunityId" ]
```

Comment: If you are not a master of `maps/flatMap/mergeMap`, you can try to first write it with plain old loops then replace them with RxJS operators afterwards

Answer (score 1):

use 2nd map inside the 1st layer of arrays

```
data.map(item => item.map(i => i.name));
```

Comment: what about if item is `object` not `array`.

Answer (score 0):

here is my way to achieve output.

```js
const d = [
  [{ id: 26, type: "Source", name: "Email" }], 
  [{ id: 27, type: "Source", name: "Id" }, { id: 29, type: "Divider", name: "+" }, { id: 30, type: "Source", name: "SupplierId" }],
  [{ id: 28, type: "Source", name: "CommunityId" }]
]

const newArr = d.reduce((prev, curr) => {
  if(Array.isArray(curr)) {
    prev.push(curr.map((p) => p.name))
  } else {
    prev.push(curr.name)
    // or use this if you want array
    // prev.push([curr.name])
  }
  return prev;
}, [])

console.log(newArr)
```